# a software -- can "software" be used as a count noun?

Tags: grammaticality

[Example](http://www.lynda.com/Access-tutorials/Understanding-entities-tables/145932/172975-4.html):

> Some people like to do this using **a dedicated diagramming software**, like Microsoft Visio.

A friend of mine, who is a native English speaker, says that this sentence doesn't sound weird to him at all. But isn't it true that the word *software* is inherently a mass noun, so no articles are possbile or is he right that *software* can be used as a count noun to mean something like *program* and *application*? I actually have never seen *software* used as a count noun like that. I always thought that this word was a mass noun and could not be anything else. What do you guys think?

Comment: Whenever you encounter references to ***a** software*, you can be pretty certain the speaker/writer is German. Virtually no native speakers would ever do it, but this was [covered on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12990/) long before ELL even existed.

Comment: To my American ears, "a software" sounds weird, but "a dedicated diagramming software" or "a piece of software" both sound perfectly fine. I think software is generally a mass noun, but if you are talking about a specific type or piece of software, rather than software in general, that changes things.

Comment: "a. . . software" - please, no. Just no. It's like nails down a blackboard. It's _always_ a mass noun.

Comment: For the past 50 years *software* has not been a count-noun in US English and to my US ears, "a dedicated diagramming software" does NOT sound "perfectly fine".  But there's a TV commercial running in the US at the moment (for managing routine employee issues) that does use "software" as a count-noun. The phrase in the ad goes something like "... in **a single** easy-to-use software". The emphasis in the ad is on there being only one package or platform needed to handle a wide variety of tasks, with no need for users to be trained in multiple systems or for IT to clumsily patch them together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My experience has always been that *software* is an uncountable or mass noun.

I would phrase your sentence as *Some people like to do this using dedicated diagramming software*.

The usual "unit of measurement" for *software* is *piece*.  *I need a piece of software for diagramming* means *I need a diagramming application*.  This seems to be by analogy with *silverware* and other similar words.

Comment: In general, I agree but I think that the "a" can be use in this case because, with the modification of the type of software, *piece* can be implied.

Comment: @Catija I think in this case it might have just been an editing fumble. The clause might have started out in the author's mind as "a dedicated diagramming program" and "program" got changed to "software" by the time the words hit the page because software sounds better and is less ambiguous. I would never say "a dedicated diagramming software" unless I was trying to edit myself as I was saying something [off-the-cuff](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-the-cuff).

Comment: That's completely possible... And I'm now irked by my lost **d** at the end of *use*. Grrrr.