# These or this two software?

Tags: countability

When I type the following sentence,

> So, the engineers use ***these*** two software.

MS Office Word wants to correct me as

> ***this*** two software

Here I am referring two PC applications for example, AutoCAD and Photoshop.

Why should I use *this* with *two* ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a software -- can "software" be used as a count noun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53684/a-software-can-software-be-used-as-a-count-noun)

Comment: *...these two programs* is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to use *these* for a plural. **But** you should change the object "software" to be plural as well (this is probably what is confusing the spell checker.) "Programs" fits most naturally there in place of software, or "software packages", or "PC applications" as you said. ("Softwares" is nonstandard and should be avoided.)

Comment: thanks! I was also suspicious about whether "software" is the best word for purpose or not. I will change it to "programs".

Comment: *Pieces of software* is also fine.